# match against not just a word, but whole table

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have two tables.

#### A

```
user_id | food
--------+-------
paul1   | apple
john2   | banana
```

#### B

```
food_id | food
--------+-------
food001 | burnt apple
food002 | green banana
```

I want to find food_id from `tbl.B` where `A.food` matches `B.food` 
all A's food column.

But I just can do multiple time like this.

```
SELECT b.food_id FROM B as b WHERE match(food) against('apple')
```

... and I would write down food_id somewhere else.

```
SELECT b.food_id FROM B as b WHERE match(food) against('banana')
```

... and so on.

is there a way to write multiple words in against? 
or do i have to write stored procedure? or anything else?

Comment: You'll need to write a stored procedure, because the `AGAINST` argument has to be a literal string, it can't be a column in another table. Your procedure can use `PREPARE` to build the query from table A.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to group all foods from table A in one string and then match the column food of table B against the food string.

But it has to be run as two separated queries, as [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) said, the `AGAINST` argument has to be a literal string.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT food SEPARATOR ' ') AS list FROM A;

SELECT b.food_id FROM B as b WHERE match(food) against(list);
```

Comment: `list` isn't a literal string.

Comment: @Barmar You are right, the example I gave is for the idea. To make it work you have to get the list and create the second query with the list in it.